# Mock ControllerBase Request using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit.net

I have a Web API in .Net Core 2.2 as below:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> SomeMethodPost()
    {
        string returnUrl = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}/some/redirect";

        //Some Third Part Service Call

        return serviceResult;
    }
}
```

I want to mock the properties "Scheme", "Host" and "PathBase" for my controller action in my unit test. I managed to write below code in my unit test method:

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>(MockBehavior.Strict);
request.Setup(x => x.Scheme).Returns("http");
request.Setup(x => x.Host).Returns(HostString.FromUriComponent("http://localhost:8080"));
request.Setup(x => x.PathBase).Returns(PathString.FromUriComponent("/api"));

var mockHttp = new Mock<ControllerBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockHttp.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
```

However, the mock in last line throws exception as "`Request`" of "`ControllerBase`" is non overridable. I understand the limitation with non virtual properties of abstract classes. Is there any workaround for this?

Moq version is 4.13.0.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change approach. Do not mock the subject under test, which in this case is the controller.

The controller's `Request` is accessed via the `HttpContext` which can be set when arranging the test.

For example

```
//Arrange
var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
request.Setup(x => x.Scheme).Returns("http");
request.Setup(x => x.Host).Returns(HostString.FromUriComponent("http://localhost:8080"));
request.Setup(x => x.PathBase).Returns(PathString.FromUriComponent("/api"));

var httpContext = Mock.Of<HttpContext>(_ => 
    _.Request == request.Object
);

//Controller needs a controller context 
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
    HttpContext = httpContext,
};
//assign context to controller
var controller = new SomeController(){
    ControllerContext = controllerContext,
};

String expected = "expected value here";

//Act
String actual = await controller.SomeMethodPost();


//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

//...
```

Comment: this is great. What I was looking for.

Comment: I had to adjust this just a bit to get it to recognize the Host in my test. It didn't like the http:// being part of the string. This is what worked for me. `request.Setup(x => x.Host).Returns(HostString.FromUriComponent("localhost:8080"));`