# Moq setup statement for HttpClient.Send() method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing unit tests in C# using Moq framework. How can I write a mock statement for the following:

```
var HttpClient httpClient;

var request = new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = ..., Method = HttpMethod.Post, Content = "..." }
httpClient.Send(request);
```

How can I mock the last statement calling the `Send` method? I have already provided dummy content. Since I am writing unit tests, I do not want my test to send an actual request to the URL.

Hence, I would like to mock it and just verify if the Send method was called. What URL should be provided to ensure this behavior, without running into any other issues?

Comment: An HTTP Request the data is in the body of the request (Content).  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315425/mock-controllerbase-request-using-moq

Comment: You can intercept the request by using a custom HttpMessageHandler. Already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests

Comment: Thank you for your response. The method I am trying to mock is just Send() not SendAsync(). Will it work for this as well? Also, I am not in a position to modify my original code so will I be able to use this technique without modifying it? I couldn't clearly understand the solution you had referred to. Any clarifications / explanations would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity lets suppose that your to be tested method looks like this:

```
public class ToBeTestedClass
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public ToBeTestedClass(HttpClient client)
        => this.client = client;

    public HttpResponseMessage ToBeTestedMethod()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Get, "https://httpstat.us/200");
        return client.Send(request);
    }
}
```

As it was mentioned by [Kalten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305465/kalten) you can mock the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` to test the `HttpClient`. In the linked thread the solution used `SendAsync` but it can be easily adjusted to use `Send` instead.

```
public void GivenAFlawlessHttpClient_WhenICallToBeTestedMethod_ThenItInvokesTheHttpClientsSend()
{
    //Arrange
    const string SendMethodName = "Send";
    var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    handlerMock.Protected()
        .Setup<HttpResponseMessage>(
           SendMethodName, 
           ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), 
           ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent("Dummy response")
        });


    //Act
    var testedClass = new ToBeTestedClass(new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object));
    var response = testedClass.ToBeTestedMethod();

    //Assert
    handlerMock.Protected().Verify(
        SendMethodName,
        Times.Once(),
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
            req.Method == HttpMethod.Get
            && req.RequestUri == new Uri("https://httpstat.us/200") 
        ),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
    );
}
```

Please note that you should youse `ItExpr` instead of `It` otherwise you will get an `ArgumentException`.